# Vertical Align list item to bottom with a Bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have menu items with varying length. I used a Bootstrap template (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/) to initially have a top navbar which will be responsive and customized it a bit in order to try and get the design I was asked to do - for example I changed the "project name" for an image. The problem is I'm having a hard time aligning the menu items on the bottom of the UL, to match the image bottom.

I have this HTML (simplified):

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="/img/logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="mainNavBar" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a fairly long item menu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div><!--/.container -->
```

with this CSS:

```
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    float: none; /* This is for the .container-fluid height to match the image height, and therefore allow for a possible bottom alignment of its ul sibling */
}

#mainNavBar {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#mainNavBar > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Actual:

```
B   +--------------------+
I   |Row1 Row1 Row1 Row1 |
G   |     Row2      Row2 |
    |     Row3           |
I   |                    |
M   |                    |
A   |                    |
G   |                    |
E   +--------------------+
```

What I need:

```
B   +-------------------+
I   |                   |
G   |                   |
    |                   |
I   |                   |
M   |     Row1          |
A   |     Row2      Row1|
G   |Row1 Row3 Row1 Row2|
E   +-------------------+
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

If I assumed this right, you have a menu within a container, that also has an image inside?

For example, this is your menu with it's container:

```
<div class="menu-container">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.jpg">
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Add this CSS that will align it accordingly:

```
.menu-container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

Edit: Updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31kvrm5a/2/)

Comment: It works only if you define a fixed height. I don't want to do that - the height is defined by the height of the used image.